# C言語で複数のファイルを開くときのエラー処理

Tags: c

C言語で複数のファイルを開いて使う処理を書く場合、
エラー処理はどのように書くのがきれいでしょうか。

以下のような形を考えましたが、2つ目のファイルオープンで
エラーになったときの処理が気持ち悪いです。

```
int func1(char *fname1, char *fname2)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;

    if((fp1 = fopen(fname1, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname1 open error.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if((fp2 = fopen(fname2, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname2 open error.\n");
        fclose(fp1);    //ここが気持ち悪い
        return -1;
    }
    int ret;
    ret = func2(fp1, fp2);  //ファイルに書き込む処理
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error occured in func2.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

こういう場合では `goto` を使うと綺麗に書けるので、使用して問題なければ以下のように書くのはどうでしょうか？

```
int func1(char *fname1, char *fname2)
{
    int r = 0;    // 返り値に使用
    FILE *fp1 = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = NULL;

    if((fp1 = fopen(fname1, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname1 open error.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    if((fp2 = fopen(fname2, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname2 open error.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    int ret;
    ret = func2(fp1, fp2);  //ファイルに書き込む処理
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error occured in func2.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

cleanup:
    if(fp1 != NULL){
        fclose(fp1);
    }
    if(fp2 != NULL){
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: r はあらかじめ -1 にしておいて cleanup ラベルの直前で 0 にする方がスッキリするかも

Comment: @ngyuki 今回のように返り値が成功か失敗の場合ではそちらの方がすっきりかけますね。要件によっては返り値の値が複数必要な場合もありますので、そのときは都度値を指定するのがよいのではと思ってます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。gotoもですがfclose()の前にNULLチェックするというのが目から鱗でした。cleanupを関数にしてしまえばgoto使わずにできそうですね。

Answer (score 6):

私も`goto`使いますが、どんなパターンでも`goto`使うの禁止っていう残念職場ならこう書きます。

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen(fname1, "w");
FILE *fp2 = fopen(fname2, "w");

if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
{
    (fp1 == NULL) ? fprintf(stderr, "fname1 open error.\n") : fclose(fp1);
    (fp2 == NULL) ? fprintf(stderr, "fname2 open error.\n") : fclose(fp2);
    return -1;
}

// ファイル処理
･･･

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
これはすっきりしていていいですね。
3項演算子も禁止だったりしたような気もしますが・・・。

Answer (score 2):

Kyosuke Kameda さんの回答とほぼ同じですが、クリーンアップ時に `NULL` 判定を行わないやり方もあります。

```
int func1(char *fname1, char *fname2)
{
    int r = 0;
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;

    if((fp1 = fopen(fname1, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname1 open error.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto err_open1;
    }
    if((fp2 = fopen(fname2, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fname2 open error.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto err_open2;
    }
    int ret = func2(fp1, fp2);  //ファイルに書き込む処理
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error occured in func2.\n");
        r = -1;
        goto err_func2;
    }

// cleanup
err_func2:
    fclose(fp2);
err_open2:
    fclose(fp1);
err_open1:
    return r;
}
```

エラー判定が必要な処理 hoge 毎に

```
    hogeのクリーンアップ処理;
err_hoge:
```

というのを組にしています。
このやり方だと、 `fp1` と `fp2` を閉じる順序がオリジナルと逆に
する必要がありますが、経験上、ファイルやメモリなどは、開いたり確保したりしたのと逆順に解放していった方がよいことが多いです。
オリジナルの順に閉じなければならない、という場合はこの方法が使えないのが難点かもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。NULLチェックがないとすっきりしますね。

Answer (score 2):

正攻法は他の回答にまかせるとして、GCC独自拡張の[`cleanup`属性](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)を利用して実装することもできます。他コンパイラでは利用できないので、利用に際してはご注意ください。

Wikipedia記事 "[Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization#GCC_.22cleanup.22_extension_for_C)" より引用：

```
static inline void fclosep(FILE **fp) { if (*fp) fclose(*fp); }
#define _cleanup_fclose_ __attribute__((cleanup(fclosep)))

void example_usage() {
  _cleanup_fclose_ FILE *logfile = fopen("logfile.txt", "w+");
  fputs("hello logfile!", logfile);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
これは私には少し難しいです。＾＾；
独自拡張が作られるということは、皆さんそれなりに困ってるって
ことなんですかね。

Comment: Wikipedia引用元にもあるように"RAII(Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)"という定番パターンですね。大抵のプログラミング言語では、このパターンに対応する機能が提供されます。C言語は古い言語なので仕方ないですね…